# Cross platform and browser automation testing on linux

Tags: automated-testing, cross-browser-testing

I thought that `docker` will be able to achieve this and so I installed it on `Centos 7` but found that Windows and MAC images are not available.

What other opensource options I have, to run my tests cross Platform and browsers?

I want to avoid installing VMs.

Comment: Maybe putting this question on Stack Overflow would give you more answers.

Comment: opinion based answers, are you sure?

Answer (score 3):

[Docker is not a virtualization platform](https://blog.docker.com/2016/04/app-virtualization-docker/). It is a containerization platform. It just isolates applications from each other. It might event fail to run the image that is built for one version of Linux within another version of Linux (for example 64-bit vs 32 bit).

So if you need to test the back-end there is no other ways except virtualization. You can either use VMs that is to be hosted on your equipment or use cloud resources from providers like Amazon or Azure.

If you need to test front-end (for example you need to test your web app simulating users with different OSs or different browsers), you might be satisfied with the services like [GridLastic](https://www.gridlastic.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Docker shares the operating system of the host.  You would not be able to test multiple operating systems using one machine.  You could only test multiple operating systems with docker if you had a cluster which contained multiple operating systems in it.

Comment: this should be a comment not answer, unless you are trying to say it is possible to test multiple OS using Docker. If Yes, how to get Windows?